How to combine two jetpack compose boxes
I am trying to create A UI Components like below

As Part of this i split the task into two , the curved bump and the rectangle.
The curved bump code is below
@Composable
fun TriangularCurve() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .rotate(-90f),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        val curvePath = createGaussianPath(0.5f, 0.65f, 0.44f)
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(onboardingSideBarColour, shape = curvePath),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            ConcentricCircles(
                innerRadius = 39.dp,
                outerRadius = 44.dp,
                innerColor = onboardingSideBarColour,
                outerColor = Color.White
            )
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.arrowdouble),
                contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.arrow_icon_description),
                tint = Color.White,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(50.dp)
                    .rotate(270f)
            )
        }
    }
}

and it looks like this

then there is the rectangular component

@Composable
fun Rectangle() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .width(20.dp)
            .background(onboardingSideBarColour) // Background color for the rectangle
    )
}



How can i combine them both side by side like the image at the very top?

You can achieve your goal in two ways:
First Option: Using Two Composables
Create two separate composables (like you did): one for the rectangle and another for the Gaussian curve. Then, combine them in a Row. Since you didn't provide the createGaussianPath() content, I implemented a basic version using two cubic Bézier curves.
Here’s the code:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            CombineBoxAppTheme {
                Row(modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(4.dp)
                    .fillMaxSize()) {
                    CombinedBoxes(
                        fillColor = Color.Blue,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxHeight()
                            .width(80.dp)
                    )
                    Box(modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


private fun Path.createGaussianPath(size: Size) {
    val width = size.width
    val height = size.height

    val start = Offset(width, 0f)
    val center = Offset(0f, height/2f)
    val end = Offset(width, height)

    // implement gaussian cure using two cubic bezier curves
    val centerDistance = 100f // you can tweak this value to adjust the curvature
    val sideDistance = 40f // you can tweak this value to adjust the curvature

    val c1 = Offset(width, sideDistance)
    val c2 = Offset(0f, center.y - centerDistance)
    val c3 = Offset(0f, center.y + centerDistance)
    val c4 = Offset(width, end.y - sideDistance)

    moveTo(start.x, start.y)

    cubicTo(
        x1 = c1.x,
        y1 = c1.y,
        x2 = c2.x,
        y2 = c2.y,
        x3 = center.x,
        y3 = center.y
    )
    cubicTo(
        x1 = c3.x,
        y1 = c3.y,
        x2 = c4.x,
        y2 = c4.y,
        x3 = end.x,
        y3 = end.y
    )
}

@Composable
fun TriangleCurve(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    fillColor: Color = Color.Blue,
) {
    val shape = remember {
        GenericShape { size, _ -> createGaussianPath(size = size) }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .background(color = fillColor, shape = shape),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.arrowdouble),
            contentDescription = null,
            tint = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(40.dp)
                .border(color = Color.White, shape = CircleShape, width = 1.dp)
        )
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
private fun TriangleCurvePreview() {
    TriangleCurve(
        modifier = Modifier.size(width = 50.dp, height = 200.dp),
        fillColor = Color.Blue)
}

@Composable
fun Rectangle(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    fillColor: Color = Color.Blue
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .background(fillColor) // Background color for the rectangle
    )
}

@Composable
fun CombinedBoxes(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    fillColor: Color = Color.Blue
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    ) {
        TriangleCurve(
            modifier = Modifier.size(width = 50.dp, height = 200.dp),
            fillColor = fillColor
        )
        Rectangle(
            modifier = Modifier.width(20.dp),
            fillColor = fillColor
        )
    }
}

Demo:

Second Option: Single Path
The second method, which I recommend, involves creating the entire shape using one path. Here's how to do it:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            CustomBoxAppTheme {
                Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp)) {
                    SideBar(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxHeight()
                            .width(80.dp)
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.arrowdouble),
                            contentDescription = null,
                            tint = Color.White,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(50.dp)
                                .border(color = Color.White, shape = CircleShape, width = 1.dp)
                        )
                    }
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun Path.buildSideBarPath(
    size: Size,
) {
    val width = size.width
    val height = size.height

    val thickness = width/4f // you can tweak this value to adjust the thickness

    val r = width - thickness

    val centerY = height/2f

    // Move to the top left corner
    moveTo(r, 0f)

    val start = Offset(r, centerY - r)
    val center = Offset(0f, centerY)
    val end = Offset(r, centerY + r)

    // implement gaussian cure using two cubic bezier curves
    val centerDistance = r/2 // you can tweak this value to adjust the curvature
    val sideDistance = r/4 // you can tweak this value to adjust the curvature

    val c1 = Offset(r, start.y + sideDistance)
    val c2 = Offset(0f, center.y - centerDistance)
    val c3 = Offset(0f, center.y + centerDistance)
    val c4 = Offset(r, end.y - sideDistance)

    lineTo(start.x, start.y)
    cubicTo(
        x1 = c1.x,
        y1 = c1.y,
        x2 = c2.x,
        y2 = c2.y,
        x3 = center.x,
        y3 = center.y
    )
    cubicTo(
        x1 = c3.x,
        y1 = c3.y,
        x2 = c4.x,
        y2 = c4.y,
        x3 = end.x,
        y3 = end.y
    )

    lineTo(r, height)
    lineTo(width, height)
    lineTo(width, 0f)
    close()
}


@Composable
fun SideBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    fillColor: Color = Color.Blue,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {

    val shape = remember {
        GenericShape { size, _ -> buildSideBarPath(size = size) }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color = fillColor, shape = shape),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        content()
    }
}

Demo:

